# How to configure a mdl-dialog in the declarative way

Tags: angular, angular2-mdl

I'm trying to use a mdl-dialog with my component as showed here: http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/dialogs-declarative

but the compiler says:

> Can't bind to 'mdl-dialog-config' since it isn't a known property of 'mdl-dialog'.
>
> 1. If 'mdl-dialog' is an Angular component and it has 'mdl-dialog-config' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mdl-dialog' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

My full component is:

```
  import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
  import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

  import { OrderItem } from '../models/OrderItem';
  import { SizerunBox } from '../models/SizerunBox';
  import { Customer } from '../models/Customer';

  import { CollectionDataService } from '../services/CollectionData.service';

  import { MdlDialogOutletService, MdlDialogComponent, MdlDialogReference } from 'angular2-mdl';

  export interface OrderItemWithSizerunBoxes extends OrderItem {
     sizerunboxes: SizerunBox[];
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'ordercart',
    templateUrl: 'app/ordercart/ordercart.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/ordercart/ordercart.component.css']
  })
  export class OrderCart implements OnInit {
     ordercart: OrderItemWithSizerunBoxes[];
     ordercartsizerunboxes: SizerunBox[];
     from: string = "";
     rawOrderDate: Date = new Date();
     orderDate: string = "";
     Customers: Customer[] = [];

     constructor(
           private route: ActivatedRoute,
           private router: Router,
           private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
           private collectionDataService: CollectionDataService,
           private dilalogOuletService: MdlDialogOutletService,
           private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
        ) {

        this.dilalogOuletService.setDefaultViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef);
     }

     ngOnInit() {
        this.orderDate = this.rawOrderDate.toISOString().slice(0,10);

        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
           this.from = params['from'];
        });

        this.ordercart = <OrderItemWithSizerunBoxes[]>this.collectionDataService.getOrderCart();
        this.ordercartsizerunboxes = this.collectionDataService.getOrderCartSizerrunBoxes();
        this.ordercart.map(orderitem => {
              orderitem.imageSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("/template/images/"+orderitem.itemid+".jpg");
              orderitem.sizerunboxes = this.ordercartsizerunboxes.filter(sritem => sritem.orderitemid === orderitem.idorderitems);
           });

        this.collectionDataService.
           getCustomers()
           .then(Customers => this.Customers = Customers);
     }
  }
```

and into template I put:

```
<button #sendOrderButton (click)="sendOrderDialog.show()" mdl-button mdl-button-type="icon" mdl-ripple>
        <mdl-icon>send</mdl-icon>
     </button>
     <mdl-dialog #sendOrderDialog  [mdl-dialog-config]="{
           clickOutsideToClose: true,
           styles:{'width': '300px'},
           isModal:true,
           openFrom: sendOrderButton,
           enterTransitionDuration: 400,
           leaveTransitionDuration: 400}">
     // ...
     </mdl-dialog>
```

with the template outlet in the body element of the app.

If I remove the configuration:

```
<button #sendOrderButton (click)="sendOrderDialog.show()" mdl-button mdl-button-type="icon" mdl-ripple>
        <mdl-icon>send</mdl-icon>
     </button>
     <mdl-dialog #sendOrderDialog>
```

the dialog starts to work.

Following Michael's example [here](https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl/blob/master/src/demo-app/app/dialog-declarative/dialog-declarative.component.ts), I tried to import these classes in my component:

```
  import { MdlDialogComponent } from '../../node_modules/angular2-mdl/components/dialog/index';
  import { MdlDialogReference } from '../../node_modules/angular2-mdl/components/dialog/mdl-dialog.service';
```

but the error persists. What am I missing?

**EDIT**
Here my app.module:

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

  import { MdlModule } from 'angular2-mdl';
  import { MdlPopoverModule } from '@angular2-mdl-ext/popover';
  import { MdlSelectModule } from '@angular2-mdl-ext/select';

  import './rxjs-extensions';

  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
  import { MainpageComponent } from './mainpage/mainpage.component';
  import { ViewerComponent } from './viewer/viewer.component';
  import { ProductDetails } from './productdetails/productdetails.component';
  import { NewItem } from './newitem/newitem.component';
  import { OrderCart } from './ordercart/ordercart.component';
  import { Statistics } from './statistics/statistics.component';

  import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routes';

  import { CollectionDataService } from './services/CollectionData.service';
  import { customerSearchPipe } from './pipes/customer-search.pipe';
  import { orderSearchPipe } from './pipes/order-search.pipe';

  import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
  import { InMemoryDataService } from './services/in-memory-data.service';

  import { HighlightDirective } from './highlight.directive';
  import { HammerGesturesDirective } from './hammergestures.directive';


  @NgModule({
     imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        MdlModule,
        MdlPopoverModule,
        MdlSelectModule,
        HttpModule,
        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
     ],
     declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MainpageComponent,
        ViewerComponent,
        ProductDetails,
        NewItem,
        OrderCart,
        Statistics,
        customerSearchPipe,
        orderSearchPipe,
        HighlightDirective,
        HammerGesturesDirective,
     ],
     providers: [
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "it-IT" },
        CollectionDataService
     ],
     bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: can you show us your app module definition?

Comment: Are you declaring the components in the app module?

Comment: here is a minimal punkr with a declarative dialog: http://plnkr.co/edit/LvEC8kjljcc06OB8LLAh?p=preview.

Comment: I have seen your plunkr and I have discovered how to solve the navigation breakage (I didn't think it was an issue caused by the mdl-dialog component).

Comment: I edited the answer with my app.module. Now I try to strip down my app to check if something interferes with the mdl-dialog.

Comment: ok. btw: right now you don't need the imports MdlDialogComponent and MdlDialogReference in your code so far. If you need them the right import statement is: import { MdlDialogReference } from 'angular2-mdl'. The demo code is a little bit different because it must import directly from the sources.

Comment: I solved the problem. Simplifying my app with only one component and comparing it with your plunkr I found that I was using an outdated version of your library: 2.1.0 instead of 2.4.0... Thank you for your help and your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question solved upgrading angular2-mdl module to version 2.4.0.